# Python: embed images in kmz

Tags: python, google-earth, arcgis, kmz

I have a series of kmz files (1000+) within one folder that I have generated of each polygon of a feature class and a corresponding image (all images are in a separate folder). These kmz's are automatically generated from the attribute tables of my shapefiles from arcGIS. Within each kmz file I have a link to an image that corresponds to that feature as such:

```
<tr> 
<td>Preview</td>    
<td>G:\Temp\Figures\Ovr0.png</td>    
</tr>
```

At the moment each image is but a tabular text referencing an image in the directory /Temp/Figures. What id like is to convert all those texts into links something along the lines of

```
 <img src="file:///G:/Temp/Figures/Ovr0.png" width = 750 height=500/>
```

Given the large volume of files it would be ideal if this could be done within python, simplekml? On another note - at some stage I would like to share a few of these kmz files and therefore I was wondering if the best solution was to subdivide each kmz and image pair into their own respective directories and rezip the kmz file somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to solve my problem by iterating each kmz and image and using the zipfile module to read the contents, rewrite the doc.kml and rezipping the files into a kmz. At the moment the images are placed after the < body >in the kmz but a more complex argument could be written with re I presume.

If there is a more efficient method please let me know...

```
   def edit_kmz(kmz,output,image):

        ##Read the doc.kml file in the kmz and rewrite the doc.kml file

        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(kmz)
        temp = r'tempfolder\doc.kml'
        for line in zf.read("doc.kml").split("\n"):
            with open(temp,'a') as wf: #Create the doc.kml
                if "</body>" in line:
                    wf.write("</body>\n<img src='files/Ovr0.png' width = 750 height=500</img>\n") 
                else:
                    wf.write('%s\n'%(line))
        zf.close()

        ##Rezip the file

        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(output,'a')
        zf.write(image,arcname='files/Ovr0.png') ##Relative Path to the Image
        zf.write(temp,arcname='doc.kml') ##Add revised doc.kml file
        zf.close()
```